# Has my Schengen visa been approved or rejected?

Tags: visas, schengen, application-status, vfs-global

I applied for a Schengen visa via VFS Global.

The application status on the Embassy's portal is showing as "Finished" and my passport is back at the VFS office.

Unfortunately, I won't be able to collect my passport for 9-10 days.

I have not received any email containing objections regarding my visa application from the embassy.

Does this imply that my visa has been approved?

In the general case, when a visa is rejected, does the embassy send out an email regarding the same?

Comment: Visa decisions are not generally advised to the applicant by email.

Answer (score 3):

> Unfortunately, I won't be able to collect my passport for 9-10 days.

Unfortunately there is no way for us to tell, absolutely no way. Everything we are going to say will be guesswork.

> Does this imply that my visa has been approved?

**No**, It doesn't indicate the outcome.

You have to wait for the 11th day. Or you can provide the required authority letter to another person to collect the passport, on your behalf, earlier.